# Positioning data labels in pie chart

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to format some charts I have, using VBA. To get started I recorded a macro of me doing what I wanted, to have an idea of what methods I'd want etc. The recorded macro looks like this - I'm including the whole thing, though the line to pay attention to is `Selection.Position = xlLabelPositionCenter`

```
Sub Macro2()

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Inosa gule").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).Points(2).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).Points(2).ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("OPVH").Activate
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Inosa gule").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).DataLabels.Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0,00 %"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0,0 %"
    Selection.Position = xlLabelPositionCenter
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent1
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Solid
    End With
End Sub
```

Next I try to apply to the general code what I learned from the recorded macro:

```
Sub tester()
    Dim se As Series
    
    Set se = Totalt.ChartObjects("Inosa gule").Chart.SeriesCollection("Grøn pil")
    
    se.ApplyDataLabels
    
    With se.DataLabels
        .NumberFormat = "0,0 %"
        With .Format.Fill
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            .Transparency = 0.15
        End With
        .Position = xlLabelPositionCenter
    End With
End Sub
```

However, this code bugs out on the line `.Position = xlLabelPositionCenter` with

> "Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
>
> Method 'Position' of object 'DataLabel' failed"*

Note that I tried using both `With se.DataLabels` and `With se.Points(2).DataLabel`. Both failed on the same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I had gotten my series mixed up, and that not all chart types accept all data-label positions. As it is, it appears the series I was attempting to move the label on was a donut-chart, which only accepts one position for its labels. To see what positions are available for a given chart, you can go to Format labels > Label options (x3?) > Label position.

[image]